# dart2js Uncaught TypeError cannot read property

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub, dart2js

When I compile my dart2js I keep getting an error from the shadow_dom.debug.js

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'st885323213750055768' of undefined`

Does anyone what this property is?

Comment: What kind of application do you have. Do you use Polymer, Angular, reflection/mirrors? I had a similar problem with Angular.Dart recently it was due to incomplete @MirrorsUsed.

Comment: This is a Polymer Dart application

Answer (score 0):

build with `pub build --mode=debug` and run it again, then you should get a more meaningful error message.

Comment: can I do this via the pubspec.yaml or does it have to be done with the command line?

Comment: This is commandline only. Its only for debugging purposes. If you use dart2js directly you can use the option --no-minify for the same effect.