# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined - dart polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm a beginner with dart and polymer. When I run the web app in Chrome I get after a few seconds:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined js_dart2js.dart:310
JsObject.callMethod$2 js_dart2js.dart:310
_hookJsPolymer loader.dart:115
startPolymer loader.dart:55
initPolymer loader.dart:33
main init.dart:21
_IsolateContext.eval$1 isolate_helper.dart:432
startRootIsolate isolate_helper.dart:97
(anonymous function) arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart.js:24907
(anonymous function) arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart.js:24908
init.currentScript arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart.js:24886
(anonymous function) arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart.js:24899
(anonymous function) interop.dart:13
```

There are many similar questions for javascript but only one for dart: [dart2js Uncaught TypeError cannot read property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127976/dart2js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property). However the answer there is just a request for more info. I have tried both 'pub build --mode=debug' and 'pub serve --mode=debug', as well as adding transformers in the pubspec.yaml, but I keep getting the feeling that my built code is minified. Arrrrivals is my app. How can I solve this?

---edited---

After perfecting my app in Dartium further, this error (for Chrome) changed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined prototype.js:205
f.findTypeExtension prototype.js:205
f.findTypeExtension prototype.js:206
f.registerPrototype prototype.js:190
f.register prototype.js:26
JsFunction.apply$2$thisArg js_dart2js.dart:337
_hookJsPolymer_registerDart.call$3 loader.dart:135
Primitives_applyFunction js_helper.dart:1066
_callDartFunction core_patch.dart:51
(anonymous function) js_dart2js.dart:103
d._register polymer-element.js:64
e.flush queue.js:128
e.ready queue.js:135
e.check queue.js:89
e.go queue.js:69
d.registerWhenReady polymer-element.js:53
d polymer.js:49
b polymer.js:36
JsFunction.apply$2$thisArg js_dart2js.dart:337
JsFunction.apply$1 js_dart2js.dart:339
Polymer_register instance.dart:170
main_closure50.call$0 arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart:165
startPolymer iterable.dart:310
initPolymer loader.dart:33
main init.dart:21
_IsolateContext.eval$1 isolate_helper.dart:432
startRootIsolate isolate_helper.dart:97
(anonymous function) arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart.js:26379
(anonymous function) arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart.js:26380
init.currentScript arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart.js:26358
(anonymous function) arrrrivals.html_bootstrap.dart.js:26371
(anonymous function) interop.dart:13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was [reported](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20280). The trick under comment #7 there let's me successfully build the javascript version on a one-off. Will be solved in Dart 1.6.